# Traer un dato de una tabla de SAP a mi archivo de Excel(resultado de la suma de una columna)

Tags: excel, script, sap, texto

Estoy intentando generar un código con el fin de automatizar acciones y así ahorrarme tiempo.

Tengo en una Tx de SAP la siguiente tabla de la cual necesito sacar el resultado de la suma total de la columna marcada.

Mi problema esta realmente con la captura/extracción de este dato desde SAP (al parecer no es un texto como tal y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Les comparto mi código actual, les agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

[image: Dato importante y clave para mi]

[image: Resultado que necesito, en la celda amarilla debiese salir el valor total]

```
i = 2 

do while objWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

PN = objWorksheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "zlp_atq"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_MFRPN-LOW").text = PN
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_EMNFR-LOW").text = "000"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_EMNFR-LOW").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_EMNFR-LOW").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").hierarchyHeaderWidth = 113
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          1","&Hierarchy"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "          1","&Hierarchy"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").doubleClickItem "          1","&Hierarchy"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").setCurrentCell -1,"APO_MENGE"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectColumn "APO_MENGE"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_SUM"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&SUMC"

objWorksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").text

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press

i = i + 1
```

Entendería que el dato que yo realmente necesito esta en la siguiente lineal:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&SUMC"
```

Probé con lo siguiente pero no funcionó:

```
objWorksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").text
```

Answer (score 0):

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          1","&Hierarchy"

Then I tried to use "&Hierachy" instead of "HierarchyHeader" in getItemText()and it worked.

sText = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").getItemText("          1","&Hierarchy")

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento del código, y dale el formato correspondiente. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.